# sed: find pattern and replace for another pattern in the same line

Tags: sed, bioinformatics

I have a file with gene_id and gene names in one line. I want to replace the word after **gene_id** with the word after **gene** or after **product** or after **sprot** (if some of it missed).

Here is an example of a line:

```
chrM    Gnomon  CDS 8345    8513    .   +   1   gene_id "cds-XP_008824843.3"; transcript_id "cds-XP_008824843.3"; Parent "rna-XM_008826621.3"; Dbxref "GeneID:103728653_Genbank:XP_008824843.3"; Name "XP_008824843.3"; end_range "8513,."; gbkey "CDS"; gene "semaphorin-3F"; partial "true"; product "semaphorin-3F"; protein_id "XP_008824843.3"; sprot "sp|Q13275|SEM3F_HUMAN";
chrM    StringTie   exon    2754    3700    .   +   .   gene_id "cds-YP_007626758.1"; transcript_id "cds-YP_007626758.1"; Parent "gene-ND1"; Dbxref "Genbank:YP_007626758.1,Gene "ID:15088436"; Name "YP_007626758.1"; Note "TAAstopcodoniscompletedbytheadditionof3'AresiduestothemRNA"; gbkey "CDS"; gene "ND1"; product "NADHdehydrogenasesubunit1"; protein_id "YP_007626758.1"; transl_except "(pos:3700..3700%2Caa:TERM)"; transl_table "2";
```

I tried to make it with sed:

```
sed -E 's/[^gene_id] .*?;/[^gene] .*?;|[^sprot] .*?;|[^product] .*?;/g'
```

But the results were incorrect:

```
chrM    Gnomon  CDS 8345    8513    .   +   1   gene_id "cds-XP_008824843.3"[^gene] .*?;|[^sprot] .*?;|[^product] .*?;
chrM     StringTie       exon    2754    3700    .       +       .       gene_id "cds-YP_007626758.1"[^gene] .*?;|[^sprot] .*?;|[^product] .*?;
```

But I want to save all line, but with another word after **gene_id**, like this:

```
chrM    Gnomon  CDS 8345    8513    .   +   1   gene_id "semaphorin-3F"; transcript_id "cds-XP_008824843.3"; Parent "rna-XM_008826621.3"; Dbxref "GeneID:103728653_Genbank:XP_008824843.3"; Name "XP_008824843.3"; end_range "8513,."; gbkey "CDS"; gene "semaphorin-3F"; partial "true"; product "semaphorin-3F"; protein_id "XP_008824843.3"; sprot "sp|Q13275|SEM3F_HUMAN";
chrM     StringTie       exon    2754    3700    .       +       .       gene_id "ND1"; transcript_id "cds-YP_007626758.1"; Parent "gene-ND1"; Dbxref "Genbank:YP_007626758.1,Gene "ID:15088436"; Name "YP_007626758.1"; Note "TAAstopcodoniscompletedbytheadditionof3'AresiduestothemRNA"; gbkey "CDS"; gene "ND1"; product "NADHdehydrogenasesubunit1"; protein_id "YP_007626758.1"; transl_except "(pos:3700..3700%2Caa:TERM)"; transl_table "2";
```

Or like this (if another missed):

```
chrM    Gnomon  CDS 8345    8513    .   +   1   gene_id "sp|Q13275|SEM3F_HUMAN"; transcript_id "cds-XP_008824843.3"; Parent "rna-XM_008826621.3"; Dbxref "GeneID:103728653_Genbank:XP_008824843.3"; Name "XP_008824843.3"; end_range "8513,."; gbkey "CDS"; gene "semaphorin-3F"; partial "true"; product "semaphorin-3F"; protein_id "XP_008824843.3"; sprot "sp|Q13275|SEM3F_HUMAN";
chrM     StringTie       exon    2754    3700    .       +       .       gene_id "ND1"; transcript_id "cds-YP_007626758.1"; Parent "gene-ND1"; Dbxref "Genbank:YP_007626758.1,Gene "ID:15088436"; Name "YP_007626758.1"; Note "TAAstopcodoniscompletedbytheadditionof3'AresiduestothemRNA"; gbkey "CDS"; gene "ND1"; product "NADHdehydrogenasesubunit1"; protein_id "YP_007626758.1"; transl_except "(pos:3700..3700%2Caa:TERM)"; transl_table "2";
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following perl script tries to match `gene`, `product`, and `sprot` in each input line, in that order (i.e. it prioritises gene over product and product over sprot).  If one of them is matched, it extracts the word after the match.   The word is assumed to be enclosed with double-quotes.

If a match was found, it replaces the word after `gene_id` with the extracted word.

The line is printed whether it was modified or not.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  my $word = '';

  if (m/\b(?:gene)\s+("[^"]*")/) {
    $word = $1;
  } elsif (m/\b(?:product)\s+("[^"]*")/) {
    $word = $1;
  } elsif (m/\b(?:sprot)\s+("[^"]*")/) {
    $word = $1;
  };

  if ($word) {
    s/\bgene_id\s+(?:"[^"]*")/gene_id $word/
  };

  print;
}
```

Alternatively, this could be written to use a loop to iterate over the match keywords:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  my $word = '';

  foreach my $match (qw(gene product sprot)) {
    if (m/\b(?:$match)\s+("[^"]*")/) {
      $word = $1;
      last; # first match wins, exit this loop
    }
  };

  if ($word) {
    s/\bgene_id\s+(?:"[^"]*")/gene_id $word/
  };

  print;
}
```

IMO, this version is better because it's easier to read and understand (in particular, the `foreach` loop emphasises that it's about iterating over a list of words).  More importantly, it avoids repeating the `$word = $1` statement - you're less likely to make an error if you need to change it or add extra code, if you only have to do it once rather than three times.  "Don't Repeat Yourself" isn't that important in a trivial little program like this, but can be very important in larger programs.  Avoiding/minimising repetition is good programming habit, anyway.

If the order of the matching was not significant (i.e. if you didn't care which one was found, as long as one was) then you could simplify the script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  my ($word) = m/\b(?:gene|product|sprot)\s+("[^"]*")/;

  if ($word) {
    s/\bgene_id\s+(?:"[^"]*")/gene_id $word/
  };

  print;
}
```

Regardless of which version of the script you use, save it as, e.g. `replace.pl`, and make it executable with `chmod +x replace.pl`.  Or try them all as `replace1.pl`, `replace2.pl`, `replace3.pl`. Then run it like this:

```
$ ./replace.pl input.txt 
chrM    Gnomon  CDS 8345    8513    .   +   1   gene_id "semaphorin-3F"; transcript_id "cds-XP_008824843.3"; Parent "rna-XM_008826621.3"; Dbxref "GeneID:103728653_Genbank:XP_008824843.3"; Name "XP_008824843.3"; end_range "8513,."; gbkey "CDS"; gene "semaphorin-3F"; partial "true"; product "semaphorin-3F"; protein_id "XP_008824843.3"; sprot "sp|Q13275|SEM3F_HUMAN";
chrM    StringTie   exon    2754    3700    .   +   .   gene_id "ND1"; transcript_id "cds-YP_007626758.1"; Parent "gene-ND1"; Dbxref "Genbank:YP_007626758.1,Gene "ID:15088436"; Name "YP_007626758.1"; Note "TAAstopcodoniscompletedbytheadditionof3'AresiduestothemRNA"; gbkey "CDS"; gene "ND1"; product "NADHdehydrogenasesubunit1"; protein_id "YP_007626758.1"; transl_except "(pos:3700..3700%2Caa:TERM)"; transl_table "2";
```

Comment: thank you very much!! Another argument to learn perl :)

Comment: btw, either script variant can easily be turned into a "one-liner".  get rid of the `while(<>)` loop (and the loop's curly-braces) and the `print` line, join it all up on one line surrounded with single-quotes, and run it with `perl -pe`.   e.g. `perl -pe 'my ($match)=m/\b(?:gene|product|sprot)\s+("[^"]*")/; if ($word) {s/\b^Cne_id\s+(?:"[^"]*")/gene_id $match/}' input.txt`

Answer (score 2):

To complete the `perl` solution, here is how you would do it with `sed`. I'm not sure how you expect your given syntax to work, but actually you need a regular expression to match the string

```
... gene_id "remove me" ... some other stuff gene "replacement" ... more stuff
    =======                                  ====
    gene_id   "[^"]*"        .*              gene    "[^"]*"
```

`gene_id` and `gene` are matched by themselves. A string in double quotes is a concatanation of a double quote, any number of characters that are no double quote (`[^"]*`) and another double quote. Finally you have the stuff in between `.*`

Now you need to put `\(\)` around the parts you need to recycle in the replacement:

```
sed 's/gene_id "[^"]*"\(.* gene \("[^"]*"\)\)/gene_id \2\1/'
```

The outer pair covers everything that should be left untouched. This is reused as `\1` in the replacement. The inner pair is the string you want to reuse as `gene_id`.

Now, if you want to have `product` or `sprot` as alternative replacements, you can use alternate strings of extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E 's/gene_id "[^"]*"(.*(gene|product|sprot) ("[^"]*"))/gene_id \3\1/'
```

but this will not prefer `gene` over `product` over `sprot`, but prefer the last of them that is present. If you want to have that order of preferrance, you need separate steps and start with the last, so it can be replaced by a better one:

```
sed 's/gene_id "[^"]*"\(.* sprot \("[^"]*"\)\)/gene_id \2\1/
     s/gene_id "[^"]*"\(.* product \("[^"]*"\)\)/gene_id \2\1/
     s/gene_id "[^"]*"\(.* gene \("[^"]*"\)\)/gene_id \2\1/'
```

Or, if the order of `gene`, `product` and sprot` is known to be fixed, you can first extract the preferred ID while parking the actual line in the hold space:

```
sed -E 'h;s/(sprot|product|gene) ("[^"]*").*/#\2/;s/.*#//;G;s/(.*)\n(.*gene_id )"[^"]*"/\2\1/'
```

The marker `#` can be any string that is known not to be part of the ID; for GNU `sed` you could use `\n` to be sure. So you replace the first of the said strings by the marker and delete the rest of the line, then delete everything up to the marker, so by now only the ID is left in the pattern space. Then, with `G` the original line (which we did preserve in the hold buffer with `h`) will be appended and then the ID (the part before the newline) replaces the `"string"` after `gene_id`. Somehow easier to write than to explain.

Answer (score 2):

We exploit the property of a hash that if multiple values are applied to a given key, the last one becomes the final value.

```
perl -lpe 'my($l,%h)=($_);
  $h{gene_id}=$_ for map {
     $l =~ /\b$_\s+(".*?");/
  } reverse qw(gene product sprot);
  s/\bgene_id\s+\K".*?";/$h{gene_id};/;
' your_file_genes
```

---

Since the commands are all the same and only the names change, so we can easily make the whole operation table driven, wherein we just supply the field names whilst the for loop shall take care of the rest.

```
for i in gene product sprot;do
  cat - <<\_FMT_ |\
  sed -e "s/%s/$i/"
s/(\<gene_id\s+)"[^"]*"(.*\s%s\s+("[^"]*"))/\1\3\2/;t
_FMT_
done | sed -Ef - your_file_genes
```